# Infopath2013 Form - Using a Drop down to tell which part of a repeating section to show

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, dropdown, repeating-table

I have a large form that uses repeating sections to show data so a user can make a better decision when filling out the form.  The form is bound to a sharepoint list which is a work queue for assigning system access transactions.  In the top portion of the form, the requestor uses a drop down (non repeating) to select which office the user will need access in.  In the bottom portion of the form, the requestor has to select an approver & a processor.  Next to these field selections is a repeating section that shows a list of all offices, their listed approver and their listed processor.  I would like to find a way to make it so that the only office that shows in this repeating section is the one that is chosen in the first part of the form.  This way, instead of having to scroll through all offices in the repeating section, only just the one section for that office shows.  I have tried formatting rules where after the item is selected in the drop down it highlights that office below but that did not work.  I've also tried to hide offices that do not match the selected office and that did not work.  Help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying rules of formatting type "[Hide this control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hide-a-control-based-on-values-on-the-form-0cfd584f-8e52-479d-9419-df2c4231d72e)"?

See a reference here: [Hiding Repeating Section and 'Insert Item' text.](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/14004/92115.aspx)

I’m not quite sure how your form is built, but it seems like you can put the office values in a single *Drop-Down List Box* control, and then build a **Cascading Dropdown** to display only the required values when the approver and the processor values are selected.

Reference: [Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint List using Infopath Forms.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/11/cascading-dropdown-using-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint-list.html)